# How to install jobscheduler js7 agent on Windows server 2003 SP1

Tags: batch-file, ssh, java-8, job-scheduling, windows-server-2003

I am trying to install agent of jobscheduler (js7) on windows server 2003 SP1 (https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/JS7+-+Agent+-+Installation+Using+the+Windows+Graphical+Installer).
The agent is installed the service's running but when coupling to the controller i got 'coupling failed'. I don't know if the software is listening on the port 4445 neither if is launched correctly.
Here's what i've got when installing :
[installation log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyEuS.png)

Need help,

Comment: [1] what version of powershell is on your server? that is so very old that i cannot recall what version you need.  ///// [2] is _powershell_ actually involved in this? it sounds like the problem is strictly java & that one java app.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey 
v1.0 from 2006, i don't know if powershell is involved,
Is there any way to install other versions of powershell ?

Comment: from what i recall, there are ways to do it ... but they involve updating the underlying dotnet framework. that can cause major problems if the server in question requires a specific version of the framework. i suspect that i would abandon using powershell for this and stick to bat/cmd, visual basic, or perhaps java. ///// if that is so, then i would remove the `powershell` tag from your Question to avoid wasting time on getting powershell upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the installer log file doesn't indicate a severe error: Windows 2003 is too old to know symlinks. If the Windows Service is running then the Agent can be assumed to work, you can verify this from the ./logs/agent.log file in D:\Documents and Settings...

If the Agent cannot be coupled then the JOC Cockpit Resources->Agents view should display the Agent  with a "red" status. Hovering with the mouse on the Agent status should display the related error message. In addition, you can check the Controller's ./logs/controller.log file for error messages.